# Разметка не реагирует на нажатое состояние

Tags: android

У меня есть разметка с `LinearLayout` и `selector`, в котором я меняю цвет, в нажатом состоянии. Проблема в том, что `LinearLayout` не реагирует на нажатия!

activity_settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_background_one">
</LinearLayout>
```

linear_layout_background_one.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"  android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Comment: И чем этот вопрос отличается от [Вашего предыдущего](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478700/197641)?

Comment: @xkor, он короче и будет понятнее тем, кто столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Comment: @bukashka101, а куда делся ваш вопрос по иконкам?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, удалил. Теперь не могу нормально вставить иконку :D. Но это уже другая история).

Comment: Ну ок, повторю, добавьте атрибут `android:clickable="true"` для вьюх которые должны быть кликабельны. Хотя не очень понятно в чем смысл делать изменение визуального состояния при клике на элементы и при этом ничего не делать в коде при этом клике. Если зададите обработчик клика через метод `setOnClickListener`, то вышеуказанный атрибут можете не ставить, он будет выставлен автоматически. Для контролов изначально предполагающих нажатия (кнопки, выпадающие списки и т.п.) `clickable` изначально выставлено в true.

Comment: @bukashka101, норм же вопрос был... Восстановите)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, так Вы же и пытались его закрыть! :) Он действительно был дубликатом.

Comment: @bukashka101, закрыть!=удалить. Его заголовок отличался от цели помечания дубликатом, а значит на цель будет больше трафика из гугла, т.к. туда будут вести уже 2 разные формулировки одного запроса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ничего не понял. Открываю! :D

Comment: @xkor, в смысле, в ответ ответьте.

Comment: @bukashka101, вопросы-дубликаты полезны, т.к. в гугл можно забить разные запросы по поиску иконок, и поиск выдаст в каждом случае готовый ответ.